# What's the name for the individual units of small foods?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have two sections where I differentiate between "types" of foods: powder and small foods. I want a replacement for "small foods" with a single word the represents foods where they are small items which make up a larger group of the food (think nuts, candies, fruits, etc.).

Specifically, what are the elements within a group of the small foods called? In a handful of almonds, what is each almond of this handful generally referred to as? I'm looking for a word that can mean *one or more* and relates to having one or more of a type of small food.

Comment: Like charcuteries?

Comment: A nut, a candy/toffee/sweet. an apple/banana/date.... Any hypernym (other than 'one' in "Would you like one?") would be contrived to unidiomatic.

Comment: I think that would be become a lot more claer if you first re-phrased "small foods". that's not something English ever uses. Either way, "each almond" is a nut, "a few almonds" are (a few) nuts and that makes it harder to grasp what English might call "a type of small food".

Answer (score -1):

Having looked up up *morsel* and *granule*, I think that [grain](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/grain) is going to be the best fit for what you are looking for:

> 2 A single fruit or seed of a cereal.
>   ‘a few grains of corn’
>
> 2.1 A small hard particle of a substance such as salt or sand.
>   ‘a grain of salt’
>
> 2.2 The smallest possible quantity or amount of a quality.
>   ‘there wasn't a grain of truth in what he said’
>
> 2.3 A discrete particle or crystal in a metal, igneous rock, etc., typically visible only when a surface is magnified.

It it includes both the food connotation and the idea of a single, discrete unit that you are looking for.

Comment: Nobody would refer to a single almond / toffee / apple as a _grain_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Agreed, but I think I read the question slightly differently to you. I think the OP is looking for a category header for really small foods that are sold by the scoop - nuts, seeds, grains, dried fruits, etc. It's in that context that I suggested grains; Powders and Grains. I admit it's far from perfect, I was just trying to give the OP something to work with.

Comment: I always restrict far-from-perfect-but-just-might-help-OP responses to 'comments', and often downvote such as given as 'answers'. Unless, as here, someone beats me to it.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you're likely to do better than *item* (or *unit*) for something so broad. You could talk about *a nut*, *a toffee*, *a piece of fudge* etc., but there's no more generic term that applies to food specifically.

In stock control systems the unit of measure for individual items like this is *each* or *EA* (leading to the horrible phrase *per each* meaning per unit). There may be a way to rephrase it and use *each* without a grammatical abomination, but it's [not a noun](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/each) which makes things harder.